# bootstrap multiselect`s selected item color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have created a multi-select by Bootstrap. Since the selected item`s color is blue by default. I have 5 items in the list, I want them in 5 different color.
How can I do it, thanks a lot.

```
<select id="caseSelector" multiple="multiple"></select>

    $.each(casename, function (key, value) {
        $('#caseSelector')
         .append($('<option>', { value: key })
         .text(value));
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#caseSelector').multiselect({
                    includeSelectAllOption: true,
                    enableFiltering: true,
                    buttonWidth: '140px'
                 });
            });
```

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when item has been selected, then the background color will be changed to blue, how can I also change that?

Comment: You need to at least post which plugin you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Assign each option a Class or ID using their value or key. Then refer to the Class or ID in your css.

I put together a working example on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ebzj60o4/1/

```
<!-- Build your select: -->
<select id="caseSelector" multiple="multiple">
    <option class="blue" value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option class="red" value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option class="yellow" value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option class="purple" value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option class="green" value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option class="orange" value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

You can also use CSS Pseudo-classes to set the color for different states. (hover,active, etc.) http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Hope that help! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when item has been selected, then the background color will be changed to blue, how can I also change that?

Comment: `option:checked {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #ffb7b7 inset;
}`

Comment: @EricWang I updated the [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/ebzj60o4/3/) look at the last line of CSS to see how I targeted the option:checked input. Cheers!

Comment: @EricWang Also note that you can style a specific class like this `option:checked.orange { your style here}` Give it a try on the example I just put in the comments.